# Debugging issue in Eclipse IDE/Weblogic Server

Tags: java, ide, eclipse-3.5

I have several application deployed in Weblogic Server. When I run the server in debug mode, some of my application stops at break point, some stops in class file and other don't even bother to stop at break point. What could be the reason that debugger works for one application and not for the other?

Comment: Is your code in sync with what is running on the server ?

Comment: Yes Romain. I made sure I did fresh build and redeployed ear in Weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you start all these application in debug mode? Another case maybe breakpoints are not achieved.

Comment: I started server in debug mode via Eclipse IDE.

Comment: hmmm... strange. Try When you look in debug perspective to look at threads list. There you have listed all threads that are started at your server. Make sure yourself that there is no more threads in breakpoints than you think. Sometimes eclipse doesn't show at 'first' plan thread that is in breakpoint. But you can switch between threads by clicking on them in threads list window.

Comment: I found where the error was. It was in .CLASSPATH file. Thanks for looking into this issue Lukasz.